# Download https page with curl on Linux

Tags: https, wget

My ISP has a billing page: https://debet.east.ru/cgi-bin/utm5/aaa5

After logging into this page I have information about my account. I want check my balance automatically.

I try use wget

```
wget -x -o /data/progs/east/345/345log.txt --load-cookies cook.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --output-document=345.html  https://debet.east.ru/cgi-bin/utm5/aaa5?login=xxx&password=yyy&submit=OK
```

log file

```
[root@c12000 345]# cat 345log.txt
--2013-09-02 11:16:20--  https://debet.east.ru/cgi-bin/utm5/aaa5?login=user15003
Resolving debet.east.ru... 195.170.55.4
Connecting to debet.east.ru|195.170.55.4|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify debet.east.ru’s certificate, issued by “/C=GB/ST=Greater              
Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA”
Unable to locally verify the issuer’s authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “345.html”

 0K .                                                       143K=0.01s

2013-09-02 11:16:20 (143 KB/s) - “345.html” saved [1691]
```

But when I checked the downloaded page I only see the login page. I've checked the cookie files twice and the URL in the browser.

Why can't wget download the status page?

Comment: If the log is complete, the last two parameters are missing. Maybe the shell cut off at the &. Wrap the URL in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

worked line:

```
wget -x  --no-check-certificate --output-document=345.html \
--post-data 'login=userxxx&password=yyy' \
https://debet.east.ru/cgi-bin/utm5/aaa5
```

Answer (score 0):

On some Ubuntu versions (14.04 server for sure) wget and openssl are compiled with default CA store in /usr/lib/ssl/certs instead of /etc/ssl/certs where actually certs are present.

Fixed by symlink:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/ssl
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs /usr/lib/ssl/certs
```